# MySQL - SQL Error (1467): Failed to read auto-increment value from storage engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I get this error when we are inserting rows. I reset the auto increment and it was verified successful. It shows a maximum of: 18446744073709551615  and I change it back to 16 and then when we insert rows it has the issue again. The only thing we noticed so far is that it is set to BIGINT 19 and the other tables are BIGINT 20. Any other ideas?

Error:

> SQL Error (1467): Failed to read auto-increment value from storage
>   engine

I am using version 10.2.12-MariaDB. 
Size: 63.2 MiB
items: 63.2 MiB
Tables: 140
Views: 42
Functions: 2
Procedures: 2

Insert:

```
Insert into products 
(ProductID,`Name`,Type,Price,MSRP,ReorderAt,DepartmentID,DateAdded,Status,QtyOnHand, DefaultTaxAccount,qtyonOrder,AverageCost,CogsAccount,IncomeAccount,AssetType,DiscountRate,Track,DefaultCost)
 values 
 (3901, 'Test', 1, 3.00, 3.00, 0, 5, '1900-01-01', 1, 0, 320, 0, 0, 29, 7, 11, 0, '0', 0)
```

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `ProductIndex` bigint(19) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductID` bigint(19) DEFAULT 0,
  `Name` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `Type` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `Description` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `PartNumber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPC` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Price` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `MSRP` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `ReorderAt` decimal(30,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `DepartmentID` bigint(19) DEFAULT -1,
  `DateAdded` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Status` int(11) DEFAULT 1,
  `Version` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `QtyOnHand` decimal(30,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `Track` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `DefaultTaxAccount` int(11) DEFAULT 57,
  `OLDid` longtext DEFAULT NULL,
  `qtyonOrder` decimal(30,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `LastRecieved` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `margin` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CogsAccount` bigint(20) DEFAULT 2,
  `IncomeAccount` bigint(20) DEFAULT 1,
  `AssetType` bigint(20) DEFAULT 91,
  `AverageCost` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `DiscountRate` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `QtyOnHold` decimal(30,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `Points` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `Amount` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `ImageID` bigint(20) DEFAULT 0,
  `ImageDate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `GuidID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Frequency` int(11) DEFAULT 3,
  `NumRecurrence` int(11) DEFAULT 0,
  `NoEnd` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `DefaultCost` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `SkipPrompt` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `UseScaleWeight` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `SaleOnline` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `PackageWeight` decimal(19,4) DEFAULT 0.0000,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductIndex`),
  KEY `prdID` (`ProductID`,`Version`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here is the INI file (my.ini located in the mysql folder):

```
# Generated by Percona Configuration Wizard (http://tools.percona.com/) version REL5-20120208 
# Configuration name dbserver generated for @plazsoft.com at 2017-01-14 18:20:14

[mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /tmp/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/data/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover                 = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000
skip-name-resolve
sql-mode                       = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
sysdate-is-now                 = 1
innodb                         = FORCE

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/data

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 14
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 32M
max-heap-table-size            = 32M
query-cache-type               = 2
query-cache-size               = 128M
max-connections                = 500
thread-cache-size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 1024
table-open-cache               = 256

# INNODB #
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 512M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 2G

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/data/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = C:/Program Files/MariaDB 10.1/data/mysql-slow.log
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it shows a maximum of"? What shows, auto_increment? Where does it show it? Or is it the maximum column value in the table? What do you change back to 16, the value in the table or the auto_increment? And is the column `UNSIGNED`? Which MariaDB version are you using, 10.2 or earlier?

Comment: So what is the maximum value of `ProductIndex` in the table?

Comment: select max(productindex) from products    >> This returned 15

Comment: select `auto_increment` from information_schema.`TABLES` 
where table_name = "products"; >>  18446744073709551615

Comment: If I manually add index it seems to work fine, it is just the auto index issue.

Comment: Sorry I was away. So, your table is weird. Given that the column is signed, it should have never grown to 18446744073709551615, maximum that it should have had is 9223372036854775807. You can get `AUTO_INCREMENT` 18446744073709551615 by some manipulations, but I don't think you were doing it intentionally, and besides `ALTER TABLE` should still work -- I assume that's what you meant saying " I change it back to 16", right? You run `ALTER TABLE .. AUTO_INCREMENT=16`, but it doesn't help? If so, the table is likely to be corrupt. What does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` show right after `ALTER`?

Comment: I don't see the word ALTER.

Comment: I don't know what else you could have meant by "I change it back to 16". If it's not `ALTER`, then specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue was probably due to us adding a negative value into some of our auto incremented IDs.

> There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table, it must be
> indexed, and it cannot have a DEFAULT value. An AUTO_INCREMENT column
> works properly only if it contains only positive values. Inserting a
> negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number.
> This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers wrap over from
> positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally
> get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment-faq/